# Host key verification failed.. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: npm, npm-install

I just uninstalled loopback/cli using npm uninstall loopback/cli.Now I can't install it again and giving this error " Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository."
Any ideas why?
My npm version is 6.13.0
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the command was wrong. It is npm install -g @loopback/cli. I was typing npm install -g loopback/cli